# HTTP request failed with status: 0

Tags: javascript

I am working on one site developed in asp.net,javascript,jQuery and sql as back end.

On one of page when i interrupt page loading by clicking any hyperlink, its shows an alert msg "HTTP request failed with status: 0 0

Can you help me please??

Comment: We could if you provided with some sort of code...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It depend on the browser, jQuery-based AJAX calls will call your success callback with a HTTP status code of 0. Founding a status code of "0" usually means the user navigated to a different page before the AJAX call completed.

Comment: is there any way not to display this alert(override this setting). I dont want to show this alert msg.

Answer (score -2):

because you might have cros issue

Add setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*") to your server response.